# C: How do I initialize a global array when size is not known until runtime?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, initialization, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am writing some code in C (not C99) and I think I have a need for several global arrays. I am taking in data from several text files I don't yet know the size of, and I need to store these values and have them available in several different methods. I already have written code for reading the text files into an array, but if an array isn't the best choice I am sure I could rewrite it.

If you had encountered this situation, what would you do? I don't necessarily need code examples, just ideas.

Comment: Sorry... but how does it make sense?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Do you have anything you would like clarified?

Comment: I think i myself explained that in first paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **dynamic allocation**:

```
int* pData;
char* pData2;

int main() {
    ...
    pData = malloc(count * sizeof *pData); // uninitialized
    pData2 = calloc(count, sizeof *pData2); // zero-initialized
    /* work on your arrays */
    free(pData);
    free(pData2);
    ...
}
```

Comment: You forgot to test against failure (of `malloc` & `calloc`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch:  This is an example of how to address the problem.  It is not full fledged, working ready-for-production code.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, try to make sense of the requirement. You cannot possibly initialize a memory of "unknown" size, you can only have it initialized once you have a certain amount of memory (in terms of bytes). So, the first thing is to get the memory allocated.

This is the scenario to use memory allocator functions, [`malloc()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family, which allows you to allocate memory of a given size at run-time. Define a pointer, then, at run-time, get the memory size and use the allocator functions to allocate the memory of required size.

That said,

- [`calloc()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc) initializes the returned memory to `0`.
- [`realloc()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc) is used to re-size the memory at run-time.
- Also, while using dynamic memory allocation, you should be careful enought to clean up the allocated memory using [`free()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/free) when you're done using the memory to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: There ought to be a `crealloc` because `realloc` does not zero the extra memory. It is more properly paired with `malloc`.